# Что именно означает (string)row["ColumnName"] и (Type)row["DataType"]?

Tags: c#, ado.net

1. DataColumn((string)row["ColumnName"] индексатор объекта DataRow возвращает object поэтому будем явно указывать, что мы хотим получить его типом string (должно вернуть как я понял имя колонки)
2. (Type)row["DataType"], а здесь мы обращаемся к ячейке с именем DataType (какая-то путаница получается там что вернуть, здесь имя по которому вернуть колонку)

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

// использование метода GetSchemaTable для получения информации о схеме таблицы к которой обращается объект DataReader

namespace SomeName
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string conStr = @"Data Source=WIN-9VNS32J8479\IVAN; Initial Catalog=ShopDB; Integrated Security=True;"; // создание строки подключения

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr);
            connection.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers", connection);

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable(); //получение информации о схеме таблицы Customers

            foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows) // вывод на экран информации, предоставляемой методом GetSchemaTable
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in schemaTable.Columns)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", column.ColumnName, row[column]);

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
                    

            DataTable customers = new DataTable("Customers");

            foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
            {
                var dataColumnToInsert = new DataColumn((string)row["ColumnName"], (Type)row["DataType"]);
                customers.Columns.Add(dataColumnToInsert); // добавление столбцов в таблицу customers
            }

            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 20));
            foreach (DataColumn customersColumn in customers.Columns)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", customersColumn.ColumnName, customersColumn.DataType);  // вывод имен и типов данных столбцов таблицы Customers

            reader.Close();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите документацию: [Явные преобразования](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions#explicit-conversions).

`(T)value` - это *приведение* типа. Значение `value`, имеющее некоторый тип, конвертируется/приводится к типу `T`.

Индексатор `DataRow` возвращает значение типа `object`. Под этим типом могут скрываться любые другие.

`(string)row["ColumnName"]` - здесь тип `object` приводится к типу `string`.
`(Type)row["DataType"]` - здесь тип `object` приводится к типу `Type`.

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, 1) "ColumnName" здесь подразумевает наименование столбца или наименование свойства? 2)при приведении к типу type object так и останется?

Comment: @Konih - Да, "ColumnName" и "DataType" - это названия столбцов, имеющихся в этом `DataRow` (и, соответственно, в `DataTable`)